# Java (lwjgl) Change window size while maintaining resolution

Tags: java, window, size, resolution

I'm trying to change the window size but not the resolution but I don't know if it is possible or how.

```
System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.opengl.Window.undecorated", "true"); 

Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
double width = screenSize.getWidth();
double height = screenSize.getHeight();
```

I'm using this little piece of code to simulate a fullScreen mode (Display.setFullscreen(boolean); causes Display and Cursor issues and will not work for me as of now).

The resolution for every pc will be different that way and in my case (1440X960) is already causing a frame rate drop from 60 down to 50 or even lower!!

I was wondering if there's really no way to change the screen size but still maintain a different resolution, for example my window should be 1440X960 but the resolution should remain 800X600 stretched onto the entire window.

Hope someone knows if that's even possible and if it is, I would be glad to hear how, thanks!

Comment: you could handle the render resolution internally in your rendering code.

Comment: yes, thanks I was thinking something around that edge too, the only problem is that most parts of the rendering engine are not made by me and I struggle to find a solution - would you know any sources around that problem that I could study in order to find a solution? Certaily I will post the answer to my problem here once I found a way..

Answer (score 0):

You could write a program that takes 8/6 (or 4/3) of the WIDTH value, so for example: you have a 1600 WIDTH, then with that formula, the HEIGHT should be 1200.

Comment: As I understand op correctly he wants the window to cover the whole screen but stretch the rending.